# How can I get Word page numbering to start on 3rd page so it will show in in TOC as page 1

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a TOC that works correctly.  My problem is that it counts itself.  It dos not show in the TOC but the first item shows as page 3 because the page numbering starts on the TOC.  I need to have page 1 be on the third page.

Comment: instead you can do a section-wise page numbering...

Answer (score 4):

All you have to do is add a section break after your TOC.

[image]

The numbering will take care of itself.

Comment: No, it doesn’t “take care of itself.”  You have to go into the “Page Number Format” dialog box and say “Page numbering” → “Start at 1.”

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to skip most of the stuff [on this page](http://word.mvps.org/faqs/numbering/pagenumbering.htm), and just copy the meaty relevant part at the bottom...

> Caution: Just a word to the wise: consider carefully before using the following techniques.  They can lead to problems in corporate documents, unless you include a warning to other uses that you are "calculating" the page numbers in this document.  If you do not, great confusion can result, and other users may unsuspectingly ruin your page numbering or your document.
>
> Now that you know about { page } fields, you're just two steps away from some truly amazing possibilities, made possible by two other fields, the formula ( = ) field, and the If field.  Want to force Word to display a number that's one higher than the real page number? Try using the following field, where braces are inserted using Ctrl+F9:
>
> { = { PAGE } + 1 }
>
> Want to tell Word to display a page number on pages one, two, and three, but not on any other pages? Try using the following field, where braces are inserted using Ctrl+F9.
>   Note: Make sure to leave spaces around the “<” sign:
>   { IF { PAGE } < 4 "{ PAGE }" "" }
>
> Want to tell Word to put the “real” page number on pages one, two, and three, but a higher-by-one page number on all other pages? Try using the following field, where braces are inserted using Ctrl+F9:
>
> { IF { PAGE } < 4 "{ PAGE }" "{ = { PAGE } + 1 }" }
>
> Want Word to insert “Continued/...” on every page except the final page, where you want it to display “- End -” instead?  Use
>
> {IF { PAGE } < { NUMPAGES } "Continued/..." "- End -" }

So, a combination of subtracting 1 from the page number, and not displaying any page numbers less than 1 should do it... provided that the TOC is the only page you are wanting to skip... or subtracting 2 if you want to skip a title and TOC, etc.