# Custom page numbers in TOC in word 2010

Tags: microsoft-word-2010, table-of-contents, field-codes

I have a document whose first 3 pages are numbered i, ii, iii, and thereafter normal numbering resumes from number 1 (i.e. page 4 is page 1). I have a table of contents but it refers to the actual pages things are on (e.g. 2,4) not what I want it to show (ii, 1)

is there a way to do this using word's TOC's? can you put field cod e.g. IF within the \p switch for the toc? or can you modify it using basic, xml or macros?

by the way it's similar to this:
[How can I get Word page numbering to start on 3rd page so it will show in in TOC as page 1](https://superuser.com/questions/420678/how-can-i-get-word-page-numbering-to-start-on-3rd-page-so-it-will-show-in-in-toc)
but I tried a section break and it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

The following is similar to the post you referred to and works for me in Word 2007.
Fields in Word seem sometimes to become unpredictable after multiple inserts/edits so you might try removing existing TOC and page numbers and starting fresh.

1. Insert a section break after the location where TOC will go.
2. Insert a section break after last page of section to be numbered i, ii, etc.
3. Insert page numbers.
4. Click on the page number of page to you want to be page# i. On the header/footer design menu that appears deselect “Link to Previous”.
5. Format page numbers and change number format to “i, ii …” and enter i in Page to Start At.
6. Repeat steps 4 & 5 on the first page of section to be numbered 1, 2 etc.
7. Apply Heading Styles to each section that will be listed in the TOC, if you’ve not already done so.
8. Position the cursor where you want to insert TOC and click References menu and insert table of contents.